# Load Subview on menu click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to Xcode/Swift, and still learning the basics.

I added a toolbar to my app, and I want it to load a view when one of the buttons is clicked. Thing is - I want the toolbar to stay static, and not change when the button is clicked. Sort of like a "Buy", "Sell" toolbar that can load the relevant screen underneath it.

Can someone please point me in the right direction ? (I want just the white screen to load when I click the toolbar)

[image]

Comment: @mathEnthusuast provide a screen shot of your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have a good candidate for a container view! [This](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/) article has a detailed guide on how to get started but I will cover the basics below.

A container view effectively embeds a view controller in *all or part* of another view controller. This is useful in your situation as it means you can place a toolbar in one view controller with two container views, one on top of the other, embedding your buy and sell view controllers.

When the button is clicked, all you have to do is call `bringSubviewToFront:` on your toolbar view controller's view and pass in the relevant container view.

I am not going to code this for you unless you get really stuck as being new to iOS development, you'll learn far more from having a go yourself. Feel free to come back with any questions and I shall gladly answer. Nonetheless, the guidance and article above are a great place to start.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having difficulties understanding that guide. I added two container views, now one of them has my toolbar etc. , and the other one is empty atm. I saw there was no connection between them and my containing view's class. I thought it'd be added automatically... I guess not. Any tips about using constraints in the container view ? As it's all messed up no matter what constraints I put

Comment: I think I'll lose the first container as I don't think I need it. I'll try using just one and see how it goes

Comment: So your toolbar shouldnt be within a container view. You want to have a view controller that contains your toolbar and two container views that each contain your buy sell view controllers. They should be completely decoupled from the toolbar.

Comment: @MathEnthusiast I have put a very crude example together for you. You may download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt48zx20gufuzqf/Prototyping.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah I put my toolbar outside of a container and inside the view directly, and now have one container only. :)

Comment: I'm glad it's all working for you! If you could show my answer some love then that would really help me out! :)

Comment: There you go :) I'm not done messing with it as I didn't have much time before, but will try once I get the chance

Comment: Well I tried figuring out and couldn't really. The guide doesn't exactly answer my needs and is too packed with information. Atm I need to figure out how to load a new view to the container by clicking a ToolBar Item

Comment: P.S Just noticed you added an example :) I'm looking into it atm

Comment: Ok now that I've been over this - How'd you add the segues to the two different views ? What option did you choose ?

Comment: are you still here ?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast My apologies, I broke up from work for christmas and have only gone back today so not seen SO. The segues are automatically created to new view controllers when you create the container views, but you can delete the container views and remap the constraints to your existing VCs if you like. To do this, simply click on the container view, and on the right tool pane, click outlets (the tab on the far right). Drag embed over to your view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added two container views to my view there, but I'm not able to declare "@IBOutlet var buyContainer: UIView!"

Comment: I'm not sure what to do. I dragged the container view to my main view there, and it didn't let me declare it.

Comment: Outlets work on an ownership basis. You can only create an outlet to a file which owns the respective storyboard element. For example, if you have a view in one view controller, you won't be able to create an outlet for it in another view controller.

Comment: The job of a container view is to an extent bridge that gap, but be aware that any elements in the view controller that you are embedding in the container are still managed by the view controller that you are embedding, not the one that contains the container view. I suspect this is where your problem lies but do correct me if I'm wrong.